# Adding PHP table to mySQL files

Tags: php, mysql, css

hey guys this maybe a stupid question for you but I have a database containing footballers names (please see screen shot) What i need to do is display maybe 5 names side by side and then 5 below, if that make sense. is there an easy way to do this?

the code i currently have after the established connect is

```
        $sql = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM players";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                // Outputting HTML and the data from the DB. Change to $row['the name of the field you want']
                echo "<div class='caption'><h3><img src='http://placehold.it/180x180' alt=''>" . $row['NAME'] . "</h3><p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No players to show";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

is it CSS i should be focusing on to make this look the way i want it?
sorry i am a new at this and cant get my head around it lol

[image]

Comment: The CSS and HTML is where you should focus your attention, for example making sure you close the <div> will ensure things line up properly.

Comment: You should do a `LIMIT 10` on your sql query if you only want to show the first 10, then yes, you need to focus on your CSS.  You can do what you're doing and have the CSS lay it out properly

Comment: as @DanDelaney commented you open `<div>` and not close it. And you close `</p>` but we don't see where you did open it?

Comment: First close the DIV... <div> </div> then CSS then If I were you I will start to use a framework not using php from scratch

Comment: you need to concentrate on css. you will need to set the width of each div element using css `width: 20%` this will align 5 div elements in a row

Answer (score -1):

try this: 
I have added a counter called i which will change the div after it has listed 5 names. Then I have styled the div to 50% width and float to left which allows 2 div side by side.

```html
<style>
.caption
{
   width:50%;
float:left;
}

<?php
 $sql = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM players";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
echo "<div class='caption'>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $i = 0;
             if($i>=4)
{
$i = 0;
echo "</div><div class='caption'>";
                // Outputting HTML and the data from the DB. Change to $row['the name of the field you want']
                <h3><img src='http://placehold.it/180x180' alt=''><h3>" . $row['NAME'] . "<h3>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No players to show";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

yes, you are doing it right way. You just need to do some css. You can take some help form here :- https://designshack.net/articles/css/5-simple-and-practical-css-list-styles-you-can-copy-and-paste/